# AWS EC2 Cannot connect to port 80 using public IP. But with private IP, it works properly

Tags: http, nginx, amazon-ec2, firewall, amazon-linux

I have an ec2 configured as a proxy server using nginx. Server can be accessed with both public IP and private IP in 443 port. But port 80 works only with the private IP. Public IP port 80 timeouts.

This server is located behind a Classic Loadbalancer. Nginx is configured to redirect http to https.

This is the output of '/sbin/iptables -L'

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Security groups also have properly opened port 80.

I'm using amazon linux 2 AMI (ami-0be2609ba883822ec).

This is the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        resolver  10.100.0.2;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    location / {
        resolver  10.100.0.2;
        set $elb 'https://internal-ecomed24-h-rELBApp-11UG9OFCA2E70-1492820851.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com';
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass $elb;
    proxy_pass $elb;
}
include snippets/self-signed.conf;
```

}

Output of 'sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN'

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3221/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2995/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4354/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2500/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4354/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3221/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4354/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      2500/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4354/nginx: master
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this.
Thank you

Comment: You say that it is behind a Load Balancer. What is the configuration of the security group on both the Load Balancer and the EC2 instance? Does it work when connecting directly to the EC2 instance instead of going via the Load Balancer?

Comment: No through loadbalancer only HTTPS works. HTTP doen't work ( seems like Classic loadbalancer connected to the public IP of the ec2).

When directly accessing by EC2 IPs. Public IP works only with HTTPS (443). Public IP HTTP timeouts. But with Private IP both HTTP and HTTPS works.

Comment: Why is the Load Balancer going to the public IP of the instance? If they are both in the same VPC, it should connect to the private IP of the EC2 instance. This avoids traffic from going out & into the VPC (which costs money) and improves security by removing the public IP on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Not sure about that why it is attaching to Public IP.

This is the Cloudformation template I used https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-compliance-hipaa/blob/main/templates/application.template.yaml

See the  rELBWeb  and rWebInstanceRole resources.